# How do I prevent KeyErrors in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, keyerror

I am having KeyError problems when working on a MinMaxScaler in a machine learning project. This is my relevant code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Root_Work_Sample.csv']))
print(df.shape)
print(df.columns)
display(df.head(5))
print(df.dtypes)
train_cols = ["feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6, feature7, feature8, feature9, feature10, feature11, feature12, feature13, feature14, y"]
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, train_size=1000, test_size=876, shuffle=False)
print("Train--Test size", len(df_train), len(df_test))
print(df_train)
print(df_test)
 
# scale the feature MinMax, build array
x = df_train.loc[:,train_cols].values  #THE ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
x_test = min_max_scaler.transform(df_test.loc[:,train_cols])
```

This is the error I get:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6, feature7, feature8, feature9, feature10, feature11, feature12, feature13, feature14, y'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Is there any suggestions on how to fix this and general practice on how a novice like me can avoid these sort of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df_train` is not a dataframe, it's a 2D numpy array, so you can't use `loc` method on it.
I guess you are using `train_test_split` function in a wrong way.
And also you are specifying `train_cols` wrongly, you should wrap each feature in a quotation mark like this:

```
train_cols = ["feature", "feature2",....]
```

Try this:

```
X, y = df[train_cols], df["y"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=876, shuffle=False)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: This is great! I have only one question about this solution. As far as I understand the dataframe has both the x and y test/train files in one variable, while this one seems to have it separated? Is that something that will complicate things later?

Comment: This is what you're suppose to do for validating your optimum model. By separating them, you can now apply whatever transformation you want on your feature space. As an example: in your coding, you scaled both `x` and `y` using `MinMaxScaler`. This is wrong. You just transform your feature columns or `x` numpy array.

Comment: If this solution was helpful, please consider give it an upvote and also choose it as your valid answer. Best of Luck!

Comment: I don't yet have the reputation level yet for upvotes but I will come back to it for you! I think I may understand! so this trains all cols for y prediction! Thank you so much for your help?

Comment: No problem! I’m glad you found it helpful. Best of luck in your ML path.